# Should a model create instances of other models ever? - Rails MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm having a discussion with one of my programming friends about whether or not a model should be able to create other models. We're currently trying to create a website where people can play against each other. Lets say we have a coinflip. Here is a sample of my CoinFlipController

```
class CoinFlipsController < ApplicationController
  def join
    coinflip = CoinFlip.find(params[:id])
    participant = coinflip.join(current_user)
  end
end
```

2 players can join each coinflip. When a player joins a coinflip we create a coinflip-participant. I would like the controller to call join on the model coinflip.join(current_user).

```
class CoinFlip < ApplicationRecord
def join(user)
  if self.coin_flip_participants.count < 2
    participant = CoinFlipParticipant.create(coin_flip: self, user: user, client_seed: user.client_seed, face: :t)
  else
    raise CoinFlipFull.new("Coin Flip Full")
  end
end
```

However my friend would like me to put the logic inside the CoinFlipController like this and remove the join method from the model.

```
class CoinFlipsController < ApplicationController
def join
  @coinflip = CoinFlip.find(params[:id])
  if @coinflip.coin_flip_participants.count < 2
    @participant = CoinFlipParticipant.create(coin_flip: @coinflip, user: current_user, client_seed: current_user.client_seed, face: :t)
  else
    raise CoinFlipFull.new("Coin Flip Full")
  end
end
```

This gives the same result, however if I want to let another user join from another controller I have to implement the same check before creating a participant. Is either of these solutions the correct one or is there a different solution?

Comment: Rule of Thumb: Controllers are for moving data between model and view or view to model. Models are for "business logic." The era of overstuffed controllers is long gone.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear. When you say "the era of overstuffed controllers is long gone" do you mean you should keep as much of the logic in the model like my first example, or that you can't put too much in the controller anymore?

Comment: Consider using a service. Fat models. Fat controllers. Fat is fat. Fat is bad.

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen I mean that several or more years ago, many rails developers had bad habits and would cram logic into the controller, whereas MVC dictates a clean and clear separation of concerns. Your take is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your action is called join so it should be centered on the actual join model. I mean, personally, I would do this:

```
@coinflip = CoinFlip.find(params[:id])

@participant = CoinFlipParticipant.join(current_user, @coinflip)
raise CoinFlipFull.new('Coin Flip Full') unless @participant
```

And then define a method at CoinFlipParticipant

```
def self.join(user, coinflip)
  return if coinflip.coin_flip_participants.count < 2

  create(coin_flip: coinflip, user: user, client_seed: user.client_seed, face: :t)
end
```

Now, the controller actually calls the action to join the two things you want and the actual model that's related to those two things is responsible for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like your approach, and we will probably use a variation of your answer. However the discussion is hyper specific about whether or not you should ever have a method inside a model which creates an instance of a different model or if this violates the MVC design pattern. Could you elaborate on your position in this topic.

Comment: I don't thinks that question is relevant for stackoverflow though since it's a little bit too opinion bases. Models decoupling is important, the less coupoling between them, the better. It doesn't mean you CAN'T have a model that creates another model if it really makes sense. Let's say you have a User model an a Profile model, I wouldn't doubt on making the user create the profile object for example. I wouldn't say you CAN'T do that, it's just something that shouldn't be overused for the sake of mantainability (there are also patterns like the Observer pattern to remove that coupling)